# How to label structure array elements in an additional field?

Tags: matlab

I have a 1800x1 structure array with 5 fields. In the field "trial" I`ve stored 14 different numbers which are indicative for a certrain trial characteristica. So for example if 1 stands for rewarded trial and 2 stands for non rewarded trial, I want to add another field which tells me the labels of the respective other field. Any ideas about how to do that?

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: Yiai let say I have structure array field of 15 different values randmoly intermixes. I want to create a second field that has the respective strings of the variable names in it. if one means Laurie, I need to have the string Laurie on every position where I have a one in the original field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this data:

```
a = num2cell(randi(3,15,1));
strings = {'Laurie','rewarded trial','yada yada'};
s = struct('trail',a,'name',[]);
```

where the value in `s(k).trail` is the index from `strings` to be assigned to `s(k).name`, you can write:

```
s = struct('trail',a,'name',strings(cell2mat({s.trail})).');
```

Alternatively, you can do it with a loop:

```
for k = 1:size(s,1)
    s(k).names = strings{s(k).trail};
end
```

Comment: Oh my god-awesome! Thank you, you saved my night! :)